# How to implement Certified Random in LaTeX

Tags: latex3

What is the best way of implementing [Certified Random](https://debrajray.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-co-author-if-you-must.html) coauthors in LaTeX. There is one potential [implementation](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-07/msg00441.html) from the `comp.text.tex` usenet group that uses `perltex` and can be modified as follows:

```
\usepackage{perltex}

\perlnewcommand{\shuffleauthors}[1]{
@authlist = split /\\.*?\{c\}/, $_[0];
foreach (1 .. 3) {
foreach $i (0 .. $#authlist) {
$r = int(rand(@authlist));
($authlist[$i], $authlist[$r]) = ($authlist[$r], $authlist[$i]);
}
}
return join(" \\textcircled{r} ", @authlist);
}

\title{Test of Random Authors}
\author{\shuffleauthors{Arthur Won \and Ardur Tu \and Auzer Trea}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately `\thanks` footnotes do not work in this implementation and I'm not enough of a `latex` coder to get it to work.  Moreover, the ideal implementation would not require `perltex`.

Comment: isn't it better to do this in your editor to arrange a fixed but random order in the source? If the order changed every time you process the source file citing the paper from elsewhere would be almost impossible.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't completely thought this through.  Although, would it be the worst thing in the world if citations were also at random?  It bears some further thought.

Comment: You need a stable list of authors post publication so that citation indices etc can work.

Comment: Yes, of course upon publication, it would have to be fixed.

Comment: but it is often useful to re-create the document after you submit so you would need a way to fix the random seed so that you got the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\shuffleauthors}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq { \and } { #1 }
  \seq_shuffle:N \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq { \and }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\title{Test of Random Authors}
\author{\shuffleauthors{%
  Arthur Won\thanks{Supported by somebody} \and Ardur Tu \and Auzer Trea%
}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add `\textcirled{r}` after every author, you have to modify the behavior of `\thanks` that typesets the mark in a zero width box.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\rlap}{\mbox}{}{} % we want \thanks not to occupy zero width

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\shuffleauthors}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq { \and } { #1 }
  \seq_shuffle:N \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq { \,\textcircled{r}\and }
  \,\textcircled{r}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_tedto_shuffle_authors_seq

% fix the seed
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n { 42 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\title{Test of Random Authors}
\author{\shuffleauthors{%
  Arthur Won\thanks{Supported by somebody} \and Ardur Tu \and Auzer Trea%
}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I also added how to ensure constant typesetting, by setting a seed.

[image]

Comment: I suppose to have the `\and` use ` \textcircled{r} ` means rewriting the `\author` command.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but a direct copy of your code is giving me `Undefined control sequence. \maketitle`.  I'm using `texlive/pdflatex` on a Debian Stretch system.

Comment: @TedTo Quite likely, your TeX distribution is not up-to-date.

Comment: `texlive` 2016.20170123-5.

Comment: @TedTo Definitely outdated.

Comment: I've now replaced the Debian distributed version of `texlive` with the current one using the `texlive` installer and it works.  Is it possible to add a seed argument as suggested by @DavidCarlisle so that with a positive seed, it picks the same randomization with every compilation?

Comment: Also, replacing the second `\and` with a `\textcircled{r}` messes up the spacing. adding a `~` to either end fixes the post-spacing but not the pre-spacing.

Comment: @TedTo I see no problem with `\textcircled{r}` (you want `\textregistered`, maybe). For setting a seed, add `\sys_gset_rand_seed:n {<number>}` before `\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @TedTo The macro assumes that different authors are separated by `\and`, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91818/discussion-between-ted-to-and-egreg).