# Implement certified random in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to implement "[certified random](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/random-author-order)" author order in biblatex (with biber). 
To do this, I want to indicate that particular author lists have been certified random, and in those cases, I want to use the ⓡ symbol to separate names. I also want to use "ⓡ al." instead of "et al."

Here's an example that replaces uses the ⓡ symbol for *every* set of names.
However, I don't want to have the ⓡ symbol everywhere. Instead, I want to use [annotations](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsection.3.6) to indicate that the ⓡ symbol should be added. One possible annotation is `author+an:order = {random}`, as in the example below.

I'd like to add the option of using the ⓡ symbol to any entry that includes an `author` field, but I'd rather not redefine every entry type.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{two-author-paper,
    Author = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2},
    Journal = {Some Journal},
    Title = {Old-school title},
    Year = {1930}}
@article{four-author-paper,
    Author = {LastA, FirstA and LastB, FirstB and LastC, FirstC and LastD, FirstD},
    author+an:order = {random},
    Journal = {Journal of Future Papers},
    Title = {Really Cool Title},
    Year = {2025}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
andothers = {\textcircled{r} al.}
}

\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\space\textcircled{r}\space}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\space\textcircled{r}\space}

\begin{document}
\textcite{two-author-paper}

\textcite{four-author-paper}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

A `bibtex` (not `biblatex`) implementation is here: https://github.com/ShiroTakeda/econ-bst/blob/master/econ.bst#L289

This other question is similar: [How to implement Certified Random in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482415/how-to-implement-certified-random-in-latex).
However, it was asking how to randomize the names as the document is compiled. I don't want that, I only want to insert the ⓡ symbol in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution uses the standard style `authoryear`, but the exact same code can be used for `biblatex-chicago` as well.

Field annotations can be queried with `\iffieldannotation{certrand}` and then it is just a matter of redefining the delimiters conditionally on this test. Unfortunately, it is not that easy to preserve the original value of the delimiter in case the test is false, so I just copied them from `biblatex.def`. If your style modifies the delimiters, you may want to copy the definition from there instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\ifcertrand}{\iffieldannotation{certrand}}

\newcommand*{\certrandorelse}[1]{%
  \ifcertrand
    {\addspace\textcircled{r}\space}
    {#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\certrandorelse{\addcomma\space}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \certrandorelse{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}

\NewBibliographyString{certrandothers}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  certrandothers = {\textcircled{r} al\adddot},
}
\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifcertrand
       {\printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{certrandothers}}
       {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
          {\finalandcomma}
          {}%
        \printdelim{andothersdelim}\bibstring{andothers}}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{two-author-paper,
  author    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2},
  author+an = {=certrand},
  journal   = {Some Journal},
  title     = {New-ish title},
  year      = {2018},
}
@article{four-author-paper,
  author    = {LastA, FirstA and LastB, FirstB and LastC, FirstC and LastD, FirstD},
  author+an = {=certrand},
  journal   = {Journal of Future Papers},
  title     = {Really Cool Title},
  year      = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{two-author-paper}

\textcite{four-author-paper}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Certified random entries with "(r)" everywhere and normal citations with comma and "and".]

Note that I slightly changed the annotation syntax to the somewhat simpler `author+an = {=certrand},`. If you want to used named annotations of the form `author+an:order = {=certrand},`, you'd simply replace `\newcommand*{\ifcertrand}{\iffieldannotation{certrand}}` with `\iffieldannotation[][order]{certrand}`. The leading `=` in the value might be slightly awkward, but it is required by the field annotation syntax.